# how can i display the properties of my models that are stored in the QuerySet object?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

My django app has a simple model, i created 3 instances, each has title and description properties, how can i use these properties to display in html template?

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Solution(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter a title of solution')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Enter a description of solution',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Solution
from django.views import generic

def index(request):
    solutions = Solution.objects.all()
    return render(request, "main/index.html", {'solutions': solutions})
```

I need to do something like this in a file html:

```
<div class="content">
  <h3>{{ solution.title }}</h3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need the first object then you have to edit your query, try it like this:

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Solution
from django.views import generic

def index(request):
    solutions = Solution.objects.first()
    return render(request, "main/index.html", {'solutions': solutions})
```

template

```
{{ solutions.title }}
```

if you do not want to change your query, you can also use [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#first) in your template to get the first object:

```
{{ solutions|first }}
```

Comment: The loop does not fit, I only need one model in a given h3, for example only the title of the first object from the QuerySet.

Comment: then you need to change your query, ive edited my answer :)

Comment: Yes, great, it works as it should, but now the question is how can I get to the 2, 3, 10 and so on element when I need it?

Comment: Great :) can you accept my answer ? I thought that was something like "{{ solutions.1 }}, {{ solutions.2 }}" etc, but im not sure. i will check it in a minute for you.

Comment: Yea, thats how you should do it